# need method to be called when an attribute is changed

Tags: java, class, attributes

I have an attibute in a Java class, and I need a method in the same class to be called when the attribute in the Java class changes it's value.  How can I do this?

```
 boolean setInstallMode = false;

 public void callMeWhenChanged() {

    some actions . . . 

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `setInstallMode` private, then only set it through a setter method.

```
private boolean installMode = false;

public void setInstallMode(boolean mode)
{
    installMode = mode;
    callMeWhenChanged();
}

public void callMeWhenChanged() {

   some actions . . . 

}
```

Comment: is there a way to add a listener or handler?

Comment: @user840930 I'm sure you could find some convoluted, jump-through-the-hoops solution, but what's wrong with this? It's simple, elegant, and it's very java-like. Generally in java we don't expose our internal fields for direct manipulation. We use getters and setters so that things like this are easy. It allows you to control your object, and ensure its consistency. A class should always work in its own right. If you can break an object from outside of your class(barring reflection), then you need to bulletproof some more.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the attribute private then have a setAttribute method for that attribute and then call callMeWhenChanged in that set attribute method

```
private boolean installMode

public void setInstallMode(boolean o){
    this.installMode = o;
    callMeWhenChanged()
    //WhateverElse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private   boolean setInstallMode = false; // Make attribute as private field

 public void setInstallMode(boolean inBooleanValue){ // write public mutator for this attribute 
  this.setInstallMode =inBooleanValue; // update value

   callMeWhenChanged();// Call your logic
  }


 public void callMeWhenChanged() {

    some actions . . . 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use a property change listener like in this example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/beans/bean-property-change-event-listener/